# How to initialize UI things when reuse a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to reuse a `UITableViewCell` in my app, but I get this error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.

I find that this is because the UI things in `UITableViewCell` is nil, so my app crashed.

My `UITableViewCell` code is like this:

```
class WordListCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var wordListCoverImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordListName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordListInfo: UILabel!

    var wordList: WordList? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    private func updateUI() {
        wordListName.text = wordList?.name
        wordListInfo.text = wordList?.description
        wordListCoverImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

I create it in the `storyboard` and link the `outlet` to the code in the other `TableView`.

But this time, I want to reuse the cell in a new `TableView` which is all created by code, so I don't know how to initialize the UI things.

The new `UITableView` code is like this:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.register(WordListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "wordListCell")

//the delegate
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return wordLists.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let wordList = wordLists[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wordListCell", for: indexPath)
    if let wordListCell = cell as? WordListCell {
        wordListCell.wordList = wordList
    }

    return cell
}
```

Please tell me how to reuse the cell.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...The new UITableView has nothing in the IB, all created by code, so I can't control drag. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: `wordListName.text = wordList?.name` in the `updateUI()`, because the `wordListName` is nil. The UI things in the UITableViewCell don't get initialized.

Comment: So do you have a Storyboard or XIB file with the cell in it or is it all purely done in code?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think what you are doing wrong is when you create a custom tableView cell, you are not assigning a UIImage. So instead try doing this `wordListCoverImage = UIImage(named: wordList.imageName)`.

Now also in your tableView class inside viewDidLoad() apart from adding

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.register(WordListCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "wordListCell")
```

Then at `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wordListCell", for: indexPath)` downcast it as a custom cell class like so.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wordListCell", for: indexPath) as! WordListCell
```

And then finaly under that set the `cell.delegate = self`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the `configureTableView()` mean. I think the crash is not because the `UIImage()`, I just type `UIImage()` here for convenience. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, the `configureTableView()` is a function of mine that has the following `func configureTableView(){
        categoryTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        categoryTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0
    }` You can just ignore that but you can also adopt it too.

Comment: In a previous comment of yours, you say that the error is from `wordListName.text = wordList?.name` because it is nil. Try applying the Nil-Coalescing Operator so that you give a default value if it is nil like so `wordListName.text = wordList?.name ?? "Example"`